# How to generate sensible error messages in azure devops pipeline from a python script

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using python in my build pipeline to run some checks on pull requests. When checks fail, I use `sys.exit('reason')` to exit the script. This works but the output is not helpful. All that's shown in the PR page is this:

> The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\python.exe'
> failed with exit code 1

I would like to know how to pass the reason to this page so the developers don't have to dig into the pipeline log to see what actually went wrong. In powershell I can use the following commands:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Reason"
Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Text"
```

Comment: Throw an exception or use `print()`

Comment: By throwing an exception or printing stuff I can only add text to the output of the task but the PR overview page still doesn't show that text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the same [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops) in python also, with `print()`:

```
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
     print("##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Reason")
     print("##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Text")
```

In the PR you will see:

[image]

Comment: Oh, right. Maybe that's what Shidouuu meant. Thanks